# Chart.js Mouse Over Show Old Chart Data

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I was having some problem when trying to redraw chart on canvas using chart.js in Angular. Here is my HTML component:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select [(ngModel)]="timeMode" id="timeModeInput" class="browser-default custom-select" (change)="onTimeModeChange($event)">
       <option value="all" selected>Yearly</option>
       <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
    </select>
</div>
<canvas id="expenseTimelineCanvas"></canvas>
```

Upon dropdown select, I repopulate the chart:

```
if (chart != null) { chart.destroy(); chart.clear(); }
chart = new Chart(chartName, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: chartData,
        borderColor: lineColor,
        fill: false,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderDash: [10, 10],
        pointBackgroundColor: "white",
        pointBorderColor: lineColor,
        pointRadius: 5
      }
    ]
    }
  }
});
```

However, when I mouse over at certain part of the canvas, the old chart will be displayed. Any ideas on how to totally destroy the canvas before replotting on the same DOM element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this happens because chartjs uses canvas and for redrawing you just have to destroy old drawing from the canvas.**
when you make a new chart then you have to destroy the old chart.
but in angular you can also just reload the component to destroy the chart

**your method**

```
//this method 
initChart(){
 //this will generate chart you need
 //before generating just destroy the old chart
}
```

**second method**

```
//in html file
<thisIsHTMLTagOfChartComponent *ngIf="showChart">

</thisIsHTMLTagOfChartComponent>

//in typescript
public showChart = false;

//this function will be called everytime you fetch the data from server
getChartData(){
 this.showChart = false; //this will remove the component from the page
 fetchData(uri)
 .then(result => {
   //do your stuff here
   this.showChart = true // this will load the component in the page again
 }
 )
```

Comment: Cool thanks so much your solution to reload the entire component in Angular works!

Answer (score 0):

i prefer to not destroy your chart just change the value of it for e.g: in your change function just load a new chart definition in your same chart with new config, we have 2 different configs:

```
config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: dringlichkeiten.map(x => x.id),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'My Bar Chart',
            data: dringlichkeiten.map(x => x.value),
            backgroundColor: ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'orange']
          }
        ]
      },
    }
  config2 = {
      type: 'line',

      data: {
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Höhenlinie',
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132,0.4)",
          borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
          fill: true,
          data: [
            { x: 1, y: 2 },
            { x: 2500, y: 2.5 },
            { x: 3000, y: 5 },
            { x: 3400, y: 4.75 },
            { x: 3600, y: 4.75 },
            { x: 5200, y: 6 },
            { x: 6000, y: 9 },
            { x: 7100, y: 6 },
          ],
        }]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Höhenlinie'
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'bottom',
            ticks: {
              userCallback: function (tick) {
                if (tick >= 1000) {
                  return (tick / 1000).toString() + 'km';
                }
                return tick.toString() + 'm';
              }
            },
            scaleLabel: {
              labelString: 'Länge',
              display: true,
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            ticks: {
              userCallback: function (tick) {
                return tick.toString() + 'm';
              }
            },
            scaleLabel: {
              labelString: 'Höhe',
              display: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  chart: Chart ;
```

in your change function just load a new config:

```
change(){
    this.chart = new Chart('canvas', this.config2)
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h83adp-chartjs-hajnnz).

Comment: I have the same problem as hyperfkcb and your solution is not really adapted. Indeed it would be necessary to create one variable per config. In my use case I have more than 20 configs.